# Grails 2.4.4 updating a user auto saves user before hitting back end code

Tags: grails

```
           <g:form url="[resource:userInstance, action:'update']" method="PUT" >
                <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${userInstance?.version}" />
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <g:render template="form"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

Can someone tell me why when this hits the back end code `def update(user userInstance) {}` the `userInstance` is already saved before I do `userInstance.save()` ???

Comment: It's literally impossible for data to be stored in the database without hitting back end code. If you use a domain class as the parameter to the action, it will populate the data from the parameters. In hibernate, that object is now part of the session and its changes will get saved at the end of the session unless you call `.discard()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hidden feature of Grails which is something known as **automatic dirty detection**. Whenever you fetch and instance using `.get()` method, the **automatic dirty detection** is enabled which will save you instance without calling `.save()` on it even if one of the field is updated:

```
class UserController {
    def me() {
        User user = User.get(1)
        user.email = "newemail@example.com"
        redirect action: "show"
    }

    def show() {}
}
```

Above answer demonstrates the same. When you hit the URL `/user/me`, the `User` domain instance will be updated with the new email since your `email` field is dirty. To disable this behaviour you can use `read()` method instead of `get()`.

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html

Now, the feature you are using of referencing domain instance as the action parameter, Grails will attempt to get lookup the domain instance using the `id` parameter of the request and uses the `get()` method internally to fetch the instance.

If the request is a `POST` or `PUT` request then it will be bind all incoming request parameters to that domain instance hence again the **automatic dirty detection** will trigger and your domain instance will get updated even you didn't call `.save()` method explicitly.

To fix this problem, just put the `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` annotation over your action and now the domain instance will not be saved until you explicitly cal `.save()` method on your domain instance.

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/webServices.html#restControllersStepByStep