# GORM instance auto persist to database on update issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a custom validation in controller because I need to validate with database.

```
def update(Object instance) {

    if (instance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (instance.hasErrors()) {
        //redirect code here
        return
    }

    def obj = objService.someMethod()

    //some validation code here
    if(someCheck){
        // if i discard it wont work
        instance.discard()
        flash.error = message(code: 'message.code')
        //render code here
        return
    }
```

In the above code even the `instance.discard()` does not work after the database access is performed. The changed data is automatically saved even  there is no save method call. The same `instance.discard()` will work if there is no database access is performed. How do I discard the changed value to be persisted to the database when there is a validation failure.

Comment: Do the check before you call save? Seems pretty logical ...

Comment: This is instance update case and as you see if the validation fails within somecheck the flow returns from there and save() statement never executed. Because it is inside the persistent context all the changed values persisted which is obvious but after I do some database access then the discard() method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation `@Transactional(readonly = true)` above your `update` action. That should do the trick.

This is the in built feature of Grails that automatically persist the instance to the database.

Please read my answer here for more detail
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659803/2405040